# Books / tutorials for further understanding OOP

Tags: oop

I've been programming with OOP for a year. But I think sometimes, my solutions to the problem, code quality and so on, is not the best as it could be. Are there any good books on writing good and quality OOP code (programming language doesn't matter) for advanced programmers? What would you recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book recommendation for learning good PHP OOP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249835/book-recommendation-for-learning-good-php-oop)

Comment: I'm a php developer yet I bought a java book about design patterns because it taught me a lot.  [Head First Design Patterns](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/)

Comment: @TimG: You should have answered that. Nice, I will check that, thanks.

Comment: There probably are some good ones, but there are a lot of bad ones too (more than the good ones, in my estimation).  Don't take anything you read as gospel.  Experience is the best teacher.  At some point it just "clicks".  But before you can have good quality OOP code you need to have good quality code, period.  From that standpoint [A Discipline of Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Discipline-Programming-Edsger-W-Dijkstra/dp/013215871X) is good (though buy used, or get it from a library -- that new price is ridiculous).

Comment: Why is it closed as not constructive? Can't all people equally decide what the good OOP coding principles are?

Comment: it's closed because you asked a subjective question about programming practices that's not easily answered with a concrete answer.  stackoverflow is not really a forum for discussing this sort of thing.  you asked an honest question and I gave my answer in a comment because of this.  when I saw your question my first thought was, "Well, I'll give this 10 minutes max before it's closed."  :)

Comment: @hey this question is subjective hence cant help you on that it has to be closed but yeah... i would like to suggest you HeadFirst series if you are new to OOPS... and if you know basic ABC of OOPS then you have many options but I guess practical experience is most important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reluctant to suggest a "patterns" book, but [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) is pretty good. It's much more *descriptive* than *proscriptive* -- and some of the patterns won't make any sense at all, until you've fought the underlying problem that leads to the patterns -- but if you read the book with the mindset that they are trying to provide a grammar that programmers can use to talk about problems rather than tools that are the Best Possible Solutions, then it is an excellent book.